# Converting 2.80 to an older version?

Tags: animation, export

Is there anyway to convert an animation, to an older version of blender, from blender 2.80?

Answer (score 2):

No. Previous versions are not compatible with 2.80. The only way to do this would be to export to some other format that supports all the features you need and then import to a previous version. In vast majority of cases you will run into problems when attempting this so this is not a very good idea. It's best to choose a version and stick with it from the start to the end of your project.